# How to get TSA URL from a certificate

Tags: java, pdfbox

I need to sign a pdf with timestamping authority, and I use [this](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/wikis/display/DIGITAL/Digital+Signature+Service+-++DSS) library. I need to get a TSA URL from the Certificates, but I have not found any examples of how to get it with `PdfBox` utils. In the `itext` library I have found the following code:

```
String tsaUrl = CertificateUtil.getTSAURL(cert);
```

Maybe the `PdfBox` library has the same utils method?

Comment: if you need to sign, then register with a commercial TSA service or use a free service, e.g. https://freetsa.org/index_en.php